# A service and a listener defined in a non-default module do not work when the Ballerina program runs

Tags: import, service, module, listener, ballerina

I have a Ballerina package where there is a rest API and a listener defined in another module in the package. The package structure and the Ballerina code are as follows.

```
restapi % tree     
.
├── Ballerina.toml
├── main.bal
└── modules
    └── mod
        ├── Module.md
        └── mod.bal
```

Ballerina.toml

```ini
[package]
org = "testorg"
name = "restapi"
version = "0.1.0"
distribution = "2201.8.2"

[build-options]
observabilityIncluded = true
```

main.bal

```php
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    io:println("Hello, World!");
}
```

mod.bal

```php
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;

listener http:Listener httpListener = new (8080);

string welcomeMessage = "Welcome!";

function init() returns error? {
    io:println(welcomeMessage);
}

service / on httpListener {
    resource function get greeting() returns string {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

When I run the above package using `bal run`, it runs and stops giving the following output. It seems the service does not work and it does not respond to the requests.

```
restapi % bal run
Compiling source
        testorg/restapi:0.1.0

Running executable

Hello, World!
```

What should be done to make the service work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to import the non-default module from the default module of the package to run the above service. To initialize a non-default module (run the `init` function and handle the listeners), the non-default module needs to be imported by the default module of a Ballerina package. Since we are not using it for any other purpose in the default module other than that, we can import it using the import prefix `_`.

Hence, the `main.bal` file needs to be edited as follows.

```php
import ballerina/io;
import restapi.mod as _;

public function main() {
    io:println("Hello, World!");
}
```

It will now run the service and give the output.

```
restapi % bal run
Compiling source
        testorg/restapi:0.1.0

Running executable

Welcome!
Hello, World!
```